# Java: How can I shorten codes which are usen often?

Tags: java, android, public, void

I am working on an Android App. Everything seems to work fine but I want to make my code shorter than it is now. You may get the idea that a lot of lines are repetitive:

```
public void ButtonKlick (View view) {


    double zahl1;
    double zahl2;
    double zahl3;
    double zahl4;
    double Ergebnis = 0;
    EditText Feld1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.zahl1);
    EditText Feld2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.zahl2);
    EditText Feld3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.zahl3);
    EditText Feld4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.zahl4);
    EditText FeldErgebnis = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etErgebnis);
    if (Feld1.getText().toString().length() == 0 ) {
        return;
    }
    if (Feld2.getText().toString().length() == 0 ) {
        return;
    }
    if (Feld3.getText().toString().length() == 0 ) {
        return;
    }
    if (Feld4.getText().toString().length() == 0 ) {
        return;
    }
    zahl1 = Double.parseDouble(Feld1.getText().toString());
    zahl2 = Double.parseDouble(Feld2.getText().toString());
    zahl3 = Double.parseDouble(Feld3.getText().toString());
    zahl4 = Double.parseDouble(Feld4.getText().toString()); 


    Ergebnis = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(zahl4 - zahl3, 2) + Math.pow(zahl2 - zahl1, 2));

    FeldErgebnis.setText(String.valueOf(Ergebnis));
}
```

It all starts in both methods from:

```
double zahl1;
```

to

```
zahl4 = Double.parseDouble(Feld4.getText().toString());
```

Is there any specific way to get rid of those same lines?

Comment: You ought to try and use the MVC design pattern: Make a View class that has public getter setter methods to get/set the values of the Edit Texts. Then, let the Activity class use the methods in the View class to get the values, do the calculation and show the display.

Comment: Have you checked my answer or did I not understand what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Instead of having different functions for each `Button` just use one and get the `id of the`Button`. I assume you are declaring the`onClick` in your xml. Just declare the same function if these all do the same thing

```
public void ButtonKlick (View view) {

 switch (view.getId())
{
    case (R.id.button1Id):
    // do specific stuff for button with id button1Id like
    Ergebnis = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(zahl4 - zahl3, 2) + Math.pow(zahl2 - zahl1, 2));
    break;
    case (R.id.button2Id):
     Ergebnis = (zahl4 - zahl3) / (zahl2 - zahl1);
     break;
     ...
}
double zahl1;
double zahl2;
double zahl3;
double zahl4;
double Ergebnis = 0;
EditText Feld1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.zahl1);
EditText Feld2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.zahl2);
EditText Feld3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.zahl3);
EditText Feld4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.zahl4);
EditText FeldErgebnis = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etErgebnis);
if (Feld1.getText().toString().length() == 0 ) {
    return;
}
if (Feld2.getText().toString().length() == 0 ) {
    return;
}
if (Feld3.getText().toString().length() == 0 ) {
    return;
}
if (Feld4.getText().toString().length() == 0 ) {
    return;
}
zahl1 = Double.parseDouble(Feld1.getText().toString());
zahl2 = Double.parseDouble(Feld2.getText().toString());
zahl3 = Double.parseDouble(Feld3.getText().toString());
zahl4 = Double.parseDouble(Feld4.getText().toString()); 


Ergebnis = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(zahl4 - zahl3, 2) + Math.pow(zahl2 - zahl1, 2));

FeldErgebnis.setText(String.valueOf(Ergebnis));
```

}

If I understand what you want then this would keep from needing different methods to do the same thing

Comment: I found a problem in your code. You have to declare the variables behind the part of calculating. But in all it was very usefull to me! I just have to declare all button in the same method and ask for the button id! Thanks :) have a nice day

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying. I copied and pasted then put the relevant changes at the top so it was easy to identify. Glad I could help

Answer (score 2):

write an utility method like:

```
private double getDouble(EditText tv) {
   return Double.parseDouble(tv.getText().toString());
}
```

and call it like:

```
zahl4 = getDouble(Field4);
```

EDIT:

```
private double getDouble(int viewId) {
   View view = findViewById(viewId);
   double toReturn = 0;
   // instanceOf returns false for null values
   if (view instanceOf EditText) 
      toReturn = Double.parseDouble(view.getText().toString());
   return toReturn;
 }
```

Comment: Just for extra lazy, have it take the EditText ID and find the EditText within the method (provided this method is local to the activity and you can use findViewById)

Comment: I think you missunderstood me. But thank you. Doesnt help me anyway. Thanks a lot for helping. :)